# React-Native переиспользование готового кода с Android

Tags: react-native

Приступил к изучению ReactNative, сразу возникли вопросы:

1) component'ом являются только Ui-элементы, или им может быть любой класс, который скажем выполняет какую то логику (к примеру по работе с сетью)?

2) Есть необходимость динамически создавать Ui элементы из пришедших извне параметров, т.к. изначально нет ничего статического, всё создаётся динамически по данным с сети. Могу ли реализовать это через ReactNative?

Answer (score 0):

1)Компонент - это `class extends Component`, View-элемент, который выполняет свою логику. Например, кнопочка, при нажатии на которую выполняется функция обновления данных, передаваемая из родителя:

button.js:

```
'use strict';

import React, {
PropTypes,
Component
} from 'react';

import {
TouchableHighlight,
Text
} from 'react-native';

let Button = class extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
   return (<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._update.bind(this)}>
           <Text>Update</Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
            );
}

_update() {
    this.props.update();
}

}

Button.propTypes = {
update: PropTypes.func
}

export default Button;
```

parent.js:

```
'use strict';

import React, {
Component
} from 'react';

import {
View,
Text
} from 'react-native';

import Button from './button.js';

class Parent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
    valueToUpdate: ''
    };
}

render() {
   return (<View>
           <Text>{this.state.valueToUpdate}</Text>
           <Button update={this.update.bind(this)}/>
           </View>
            );
}

update() {
    this.setState({valueToUpdate: 'Updated!'});
}

}
```

Логика по работе с сетью запихивается во внутреклассовый метод, например в метод `update` в примере. Если метод используется в нескольких классах, его можно экспортировать:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

const getSomething = (data, callback) => {

fetch('someurl/get/something.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
                           data: data
                           })
      })
.then((response) => { return response.json() })
.then((responseData) => { return responseData; })
.then((newData) => {
      callback(newData);
      })

}

export default getSomething;
```

И вызывать из компонента:

```
...
import getSomething from './getSomething.js';
...
update(newData) {
this.setState({data: newData});
}
...
getSomething(this.state.data, this.update.bind(this));
...
```

2)Динамическое создание View-элементов выглядит как-то так:

```
...
let myViews=[];

class Parent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
   return (<View>
           {myViews}
           <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._addView}>
           <Text>AddView</Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
           </View>
            );
}

_addView() {
    myViews.push((<Text>New View is created!</Text>));
}

}
```

Насчёт использования кода с Android, я поднял здесь эту тему и сам жду ответа: [React Native: Android UI component](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624190/react-native-android-ui-component)