# React Native: Android UI component

Tags: java, android, activity, reactjs, react-native

Нужно подключить компонент:

```
public class MyComponent extends Activity {
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myComponent);
    ...
}
...
}
```

Для него создаю класс `Manager`:

```
public class MyComponentManager extends SimpleViewManager<MyComponent> {

 public static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyComponent";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    private ThemedReactContext mContext = null;
    private Activity mActivity = null;

    @Override
    protected MyComponent createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        mContext = context;
        return new MyComponent(mContext);
    }

    public MyComponentManager(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }
}
```

,класс `Package`:

```
public class MyComponentPackage implements ReactPackage {

private Activity mActivity = null;

public MyComponentPackage(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public List<NativeModule>
createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager>
createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
            new MyComponentManager(mActivity)
    );
}
}
```

и достаю его в файле `myComponent.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    View,
    requireNativeComponent
} from 'react-native';

export default requireNativeComponent('MyComponent');
```

Только в `MyComponentManager` в `SimpleViewManager` должен подаваться `class extends View`, а у меня - `Activity`. Как мне подключить мой компонент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, класс Package всего-то нужно зарегистрировать в файле MainApplication.java:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new MyComponentPackage() 
  );
}
```

До этого, конечно, можно и самому додуматься, но тот факт, что официальном мануале ни единого упоминания про это, вводит в заблуждение. Также в myComponent.js нужно указать дефолтные проптайпы:

```
import React, {
    PropTypes
} from 'react';

import {
    View,
    requireNativeComponent
} from 'react-native';

let iface = {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    propTypes: {
        ...View.propTypes
    }
};

export default requireNativeComponent('MyComponent', iface);
```

Наследовать от вью мою активити не нужно, а просто из вью класса её запустить:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MyComponent.class);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

А есть необходимость ваш компонент наследовать от активити? Если нет необходимости - делайте кастом вью:

```
public
class
MyComponent extends FrameLayout {

    public MyComponent(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        Layoutinflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myComponent, this, true);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Второй аргумент в методе `inflate` кидал ошибку. Я поставил `null`. Теперь вижу белый экран и маленькую красную точку в левом верхнем углу.

Comment: Layout самый простой: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/blue" tools:context="com.myapp.MyComponent"> <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="HELLO WORLD"/> </LinearLayout>`

Comment: я ошибся, смените `extends View` на `extends FrameLayout` и верните второй аргумент, белый экран вы видите потому что ваш лайоут не приатачился к кастом вью, так как убрали второй аргумент

Comment: то же самое. Белый экран и маленькая красная точка в левом верхнем углу.

Comment: может, потому что ccылки на `xmlns:android` и `xmlns:tools` в корневом лэйауте `myComponent.xml` подсвечены красным со словами "URI is not registered"? И тоже непонятно, что за дела >_<

Comment: второй аргумент вернули?

Comment: /*минимальная длина коммента 15 символов*/ да :(